# Get azure machine size price via command

Tags: azure

I would like to create a script for create `vm`. I managed to get the name of the sizes (`standard_ds2, standard_a2` etc).
Now I would like to calculate the price of each and choose the cheapest size (I have all other info such as os and disktype) how can I do that on bash script or other linux lang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Billing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview), which is accessible via API and Powershell.